# Digits number theory problem.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the smallest number A such that that the sum of the digits of A are 2009 and A is a multiple of 2009?

Comment: at least there exists one such number: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123918/find-smallest-number-which-is-divisible-to-n-and-its-digits-sums-to-n

Comment: If you take only 9's, that makes the number minimal (ignoring the modular condition); since $\lceil\frac{2009}{9}\rceil=224$, you will need at least 224 digits.  It is very likely 224 digits will suffice: 223 9's and one 2, 222 9's, one 8, and one 3, etc.

Comment: In case it helps, $2009=7\times7\times41$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notation: $[ a, (b)^i]$ for the integer whose decimal digits are $a$ followed by $i$ $b$'s, etc. 
Building on Vadim's hint: first I looked at 
 $[2, (9)^{223}]$ (not a multiple of $2009$),
then $[3,(9)^i, 8, (9)^{222-i}]$ for $i = 0$ to $222$ (no multiples of $2009$),
then $[4,(9)^i,7,(9)^{222-i}]$ and
$[4,(9)^i, 8, (9)^j,8,(9)^{221-i-j}]$ for $i+j \le 221$: $48$ cases, 
of which the least is $[4,(9)^2,8,(9)^{170},8,(9)^{49}]$, i.e.
$$ \eqalign{
&4998999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999\cr
&9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999\cr
&999999999999999999999989999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999}$$